# I want to record audio input using javascript and save it to disk

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio

Hi I am a beginner so I am not having much knowledge about javascript so kindly help me in solving my issue.
I am facing problem in saving audio input. The audio which is saved onto the disk is somehow corrupted and not proper (.mp3/.wav) file.

Here is my javascript code

```
  function saveBlob(blob, fileName) {
      var a = document.createElement("a");
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.style = "display: none";
      
      var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      a.href = url;
      a.download = fileName;
      a.click();
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }

  function startRecording(){

    var device = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true});
    var items = [];
    device.then( stream => {
      var recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
      recorder.ondataavailable = e => {

        items.push(e.data);
        if(recorder.state == "inactive")
        {
          var blob = new Blob(items, {type: 'audio/wav'});
          alert(blob.type);
          saveBlob(blob, 'myRecording.wav');
        }
      }

      recorder.start();
      setTimeout(()=>{
        recorder.stop();
      }, 4000);

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you save the file with the wrong mimeType. As far as I know there is no browser which can record WAV files out of the box.

A quick fix would be to change the part which creates the file.

```
var blob = new Blob(items, {type: recorder.mimeType});
alert(blob.type);
saveBlob(blob, `myRecording.wav${blob.type.split('/')[1].split(';')[0]}`);
```

Or you could use a package like [extendable-media-recorder](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/extendable-media-recorder) which allows to record WAV files directly.